# partial search a dash value in a field in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

my mysql table name is: student having 3 fields id(pk, auto increment), name(varchar 200) and student_id(varchar 200)
values are lik

```
id name  student_id
1  abc   123-234
2  efg   2345678
3  xyz   1234-9
4. pxy   323-289
```

now i want to select those students whose id like 3-2

```
SELECT * FROM student 
WHERE student_id like '%3-2%'
```

unfortunately the query return zero result.
any help is highly appreciable.

Comment: Expected output is 123-234  ?

Comment: expected output is id no 1 & 4

Comment: '%3-2% this really works when I check on mine

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM student 
WHERE student_id like '%3-2%'
```

This works alright when I tested on MySql using PhpMyadmin.
If you use some other SQL, then try replacing single quotes to double quotes (' ' to " ").

Try firing the following query.

```
SELECT * FROM student 
WHERE student_id like "%3-2%"
```